# Using Named Ranges in Excel with a selection of cells?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, openpyxl

**Is it possible in Excel to use a defined named range such as `myArray` refers to `=summary_data!$C$2:$H$6`**

**Then use this name in another sheet to paste the contents of the data to a given range `=summary_data!$C$2:$H$6`**

The reason to do this is that I am injecting data into other sheets in a template and the front sheet takes the data from many sheets.

Currently I can do this with single cells using the following but defining each individual cell is tedious:

`=INDIRECT("'" &V1& "'!" & "summary_data_C2")`  a name is set to summary_data_C2 an V1 contains the worksheet name.

Comment: FWIW openpyxl >= 2.4 doesn't care either if you're planning to use your templates with it or add your own: defined names are just constants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you highlight the corresponding range in the other sheet and enter

```
=myArray
```

as an array formula using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> it will set up a link to the original sheet for each cell.