# Pandas: add several dataframes to a single Excel file

Tags: python, pandas

I need to add several `df` to one excel and I want that they looks like 
[image]. 
Is any function in `pandas`. that can make it?

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34945456/is-it-possible-to-insert-a-worksheet-into-an-existing-workbook-using-python) and also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35604888/how-to-persist-excel-references-in-formulas-across-worksheets-where-the-workshee)

Comment: and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37320355/using-named-ranges-in-excel-with-a-selection-of-cells)  I had to create a template sheet with named ranges, then append sheets of data to display.

Answer (score 1):

For the layout, see [`to_excel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) docs.
Note that you will have to pass it a `pd.ExcelWriter` object instead of a path string and then call its `save` method to be able to save multiple dataframes to the same excel file (same or different sheet).

For the design itself, that would require some fiddling around with `openpyxl`.

You can try a library that I wrote, called `StyleFrame` (documented on [github](https://github.com/DeepSpace2/StyleFrame) and [readthedocs](http://styleframe.readthedocs.io)), and see if it answers your needs.